# How to pass specific query strings in a URI using .htaccess file? (e.g. from domain.com/ce/hello-world/ce/ to domain.com/hello-world/ce/ )

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, uri

I'm developing a website and have a htaccess rule as follows:

`RewriteRule ^(ac|bc|cd)/(.*) $2?folder=$1 [L,QSA]`

But, I want to pass all requests having /ab/ or /bc/ or /cd/ or any URI with two letters between slashes /../ right after the domain.com (i.e. domain.com/ab/, domain.com/ac/, domain.com/ad/, ...) from http://domain.com/ab/hello-world/ to http://domain.com/hello-world/, or from http://domain.com/ab/cf/hello-world/ to http://domain.com/cf/hello-world, or from http://domain.com/ce/hello-world/ce/ to http://domain.com/hello-world/ce/. Note that I only wanna pass the above query strings which appear right after .com (e.g. .com/ax/ or .com/re/, etc) not in the middle or end of the URI.

Comment: But if URL becomes `/hello-world/` in browser how will you know which folder it is?

Comment: @anubhava, `http://domain.com/hello-world/` reads from the main `public_html` folder, and for example `http://domain.com/ab/hello-world/` reads from the `/ab/` folder. But, lets assume there is a URI in the `/ab/` folder like `http://domain.com/ab/hello-world/ab/hello-world/`, so in this case, the URI is in the /ab/ folder, and should pass the first /ab/ to read the codes from main folder (should not pass the second /ab/). basically I just wanna add a rule for two letters right after the .com (.com/ab/)

Comment: But that rule you already have right?

Comment: @anubhava, yes I have this rule `RewriteRule ^(ac|bc|cd)/(.*) $2?folder=$1 [L,QSA]`. The problem is that this rule conflicts with the URLs having ac, bc, and cd even between the dashes. For instance, a URL like `http://domain.com/hello-world-ac/` generates an error because it has -ac in. This is the reason I should narrow the rule to pass /ac/ right after the `.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(ac|bc|cd)/(.+) $2?folder=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this solved the problem, also I did some php coding as well in the config files.